# Enable Graphics Card or Change Aspect Ratio in Safe Mode?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, resolution, gpu, safe-mode

Is there a way to enable my GPU in safe mode?

"why would you do that", you ask?
Well, my main screen burnt out after so many years of use. i'm now using my old samsung smart tv as a screen, but it only works in safe mode, and there's nothing i can do about it until i fix my old screen.
if i'm to stay in safemode (with networking) until then, i'd rather have a resolution that doesn't stretch my screen side to side, as the television is 16:9 but the aspect ratio right now is 4:3, making it very stretched.

if there's a way to just change the resolution to something custom (say, 16:9) in safe mode without my gpu, then that'd also be interesting, but i'd really like to be able to play my games before my screen is repaired, as well.

Edit:
I forgot to mention that I was able to enable sound in safe mode. I figured that I'd be able to use a similar process for the GPU or the aspect ratio.

This is how I did it:
At my `cmd` prompt, I entered

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\Minimal\AudioEndpointBuilder" /VE /T REG_SZ /F /D "Service"
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\Minimal\MMCSS" /VE /T REG_SZ /F /D "Service"
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\Minimal\Audiosrv" /VE /T REG_SZ /F /D "Service"
net start AudioEndpointBuilder
net start MMCSS
net start Audiosrv
```

What can I do?

Comment: What type of connection are you using to connect your pc to the tv? VGA, HDMI, DVI?

Answer (score 1):

You **can not load a video card driver in safe mode**.

The purpose of safe mode is explicitly for *avoiding* as many drivers as possible and have a means of using the computer with *only* the most essential functionality enabled. It is a built-in means of *disabling* the video driver; Allowing a video driver to be loaded in safe mode would defeat the entire reason to have the mode.

To the best of my knowledge, you also **can not change the available resolutions in safe mode**. This is because safe mode is listing the most basic display modes that *all* GPUs must support. These modes do not include 16:9 resolutions. (And that is OK because all 16:9 screens can display 4:3 images without cropping or shrinking.)

Your TV probably has a setting on its own menus called "Picture Size" or "Aspect Ratio".
You can change this setting to change how the TV scales the video signal.

Comment: i've read someone was able to change the resolutions in safe-mode though. that was in 2011, so i doubt the user who did it will ever respond to my messages.

edit: i did find the "picture size" as you instructed, thank you - but would i not be able to use a 16:9 AR?

Comment: @fuyuno, It's been a long time since I've seen the resolution options in safe mode personally. I have never seen a 16:9 resolution in safe mode, but I do recall seeing multiple 4:3 resolutions (from 640x480 to 1280x1024). Consider that all widescreen monitors can easily display 4:3 without losing any image content, but letterbox monitors normally shrink 16:9 images to fit. The "safer" aspect ratio would be 4:3 for all displays, and that's probably why Microsoft didn't bother supporting 16:9 in safe mode.

Comment: how can i add 16:9 to safe mode AR's?

Comment: @fuyuno, You can't. Safe mode is using **very** basic display driver that accesses only the most essential functions that *all* video cards implement. Part of that mandatory functionality is support for a handful of specific 4:3 resolutions that have been supported since the very early years of discrete computer graphics. Your BIOS uses these very same functions to display its menus and boot screen because it doesn't use a fully featured driver either.

Comment: that's sad... should i try uninstalling my gpu drivers then, and updating it once i'm in normal mode?

Comment: @fuyuno, I honestly have no idea why your Samsung TV only works with safe mode in the first place. You should open a new question for that issue.